# Images duplicating when adding to Array

Tags: ios, swift, image

I am using DKImagePickerController to select multiple images, displaying them on my VC and them when I press a button they upload to Parse.

I load 7 images, but only the ones visible on the screen (Which is 4, as I am using a collectionView with a horizontal scroll) upload at the begining then if I scroll across to the end and upload again It uploads all 7 images. And if I scroll back and then forwards again the images seem to add up 7 at a time, so if I scrolled 4 times back and forth I would end up uploading 28 images when I only selected 7!!

I'm guessing it something to do with the way I add the images I have selected to the image Array which I am doing in the cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Here is my code below, if anyone has incounted this before or knows the issue you help is very much appreciated!

```
    @IBOutlet weak var previewOrShareButton: UIBarButtonItem!
   @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    var assets: [DKAsset]?

    var images = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func selectImage(sender: AnyObject) {
        let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()

        pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
            print("didSelectAssets")
            self.assets = assets

           self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
        pickerController.defaultSelectedAssets = self.assets
        pickerController.maxSelectableCount =  7
        pickerController.allowMultipleTypes = false

        self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true) {}


    }


    @IBAction func postButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let post = PFObject(className: "Post")

        post["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.username

        for i in self.images.indices {
            let imageData = self.images[i].lowestQualityJPEGNSData 
            let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.JPEG", data: imageData)

        post["imageArray\(i)"] = imageFile

        }


        post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock ({(success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error  == nil {
            }})
     }

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.assets?.count ?? 0
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BlogCollectionViewCell
        let asset = self.assets![indexPath.row]



        asset.fetchOriginalImageWithCompleteBlock { (image, info) -> Void in

           cell.image.image = image

          self.images.append(image!)
        }

        print(images)

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything in your cellForRow will run every time a cell is scrolled to so it's fetching too many images. Ideally add the following to your viewDidLoad unless you need to the user to download the images then add this to a button:

```
for object in assets {
    object.fetchOriginalImageWithCompleteBlock { (image, info) -> Void in

      self.images.append(image!)
      pickerController.reloadData()

    }
}
```

That will load all of the images into the array and then you can populate your cells with the images:

```
cell.image = images[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Hey! to add the "asset.fetchOriginalImage...." I have to have let asset = self.assets![indexPath.row]
        So I'm not sure if I can add that to my button

Comment: I've change the loop to go through each item in the array so the fetchOriginalImage should work now

Comment: hmm, I get this "fatal error: Array index out of range", if I put it either in viewDidLoad or button, but It cant be in ViewDidLoad anyway because I'm downloading them

Comment: Can you update the code in your question and indicate which line has the error

Comment: Actually It just worked now...And uploades the images but doesn't seem to display them! heres two screen shots http://i.stack.imgur.com/EKO5Q.png  http://i.stack.imgur.com/PgNCj.png

Comment: Ah ok good, looks like you just need to reload the data, see my update

Comment: I added CollectionView.reloadData as I cannot put pickercontroller.reloadata. But I'm getting the same error as I mentioned above in the cellForItemAtIndex

Comment: And yet again thank you very much! I left my code as before but removed the way I added the images to the array from CellForItemAtIndexPath and used your method..!

Comment: Glad I could help again! Don't get too comfortable with Parse as it's shutting down. CloudKit and perhaps Firebase are worth learning if you haven't already

Comment: Well, yeh I definetly will be learning firebase soon. But my plan at the moment, as I have basically nearly finished my app is too continue developing it with parse for a couple more weeks and then merge it to aws as suggested by parse..What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are doing it in wrong way, as you are fetching the images in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and then adding the images in array in the same method. So when you scroll your UICollectionView then images will fetched and added to the array as cellForItemAtIndexPath will called when you scroll or reload your UICollectionView.

I will make some changes in your code, hope it will help you.

```
@IBAction func selectImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()

    pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
        print("didSelectAssets")
        assets.fetchOriginalImageWithCompleteBlock { (image, info) -> Void in
           self.images.append(image!)
           self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    pickerController.defaultSelectedAssets = self.assets
    pickerController.maxSelectableCount =  7
    pickerController.allowMultipleTypes = false
    self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true) {}
}
```

and then cellForItemAtIndexPath will be

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BlogCollectionViewCell
    let asset = self.assets![indexPath.row]
    cell.image.image = image
    return cell
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer. To add the "asset.fetchOriginalImage...." I have to have let asset = self.assets![indexPath.row]
        So I'm not sure if I can add that to my button P.s it doesn't work if I use assetts either.

Comment: yes, like i mentioned in my comment, I cannot add: assets.fetchOriginalImageWithCompleteBlock { (image, info) -> Void in
          as "assets " has no member fetchoriginalimage...

Comment: Right now I am not on my pc, so not able to check the code. But you have to convert the DKAsset object to AVAsset object then this code will work, as you can't do it in cellForItem

Comment: Just looking at your code again, In the cellForItem... the cell.image.image = image(<- I'm sure I'll probably get an error for that last bit " = image" wont I?

Comment: Yes sorry for that, do it like this 'cell.image.image = self.images[indexpath.row]'